# How big does the Martian supply chain need to be, to be self sufficient?

Tags: mars, colonization, manufacturing, economics, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

Something I've been pondering recently is how big the manufacturing base needs to be to manufacture everything in the manufacturing base. Big in this case referring to total mass, machines required, person count, etc. This is just a [Von Neumann probe](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S009457652100117X) mass estimate thing, but with the requirements relaxed a little because a Mars supply chain doesn't need to travel around. Obviously everything will be redesigned with being manufactured with a few core tools to reduce the footprint, but there's still a lot of things to make to make everything it need. You could just chuck out [whatever mass estimate](https://youtu.be/H7Uyfqi_TE8?t=1537) you want, but I wouldn't mind knowing a little bit more depth.

If this question is too broad, restrict the supply chain to just being manufacturing the chips needed to supply a Mars civilisation. On a technical level, this is one of the least economical/pragmatic things to make on Mars because the product mass is tiny compared and they're hard to make. But that makes it good on the principle of understanding the complexity of what it would take. Or you could just do an estimate of a supply chain you're familiar with.

Comment: a similar question could also be proposed in [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) thought I'd first propose the question in their meta area first